# cross-site scripting issue in salesforce

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my component which uses salesforce highcharts

```
var FILTERS = {!filtersJSON};

function addFilters() {
        var pickers = [];
        console.log('FILTERS===> ' + FILTERS);
        for (var i=0; i<FILTERS.length; i++) {
            var picker = addPicker2(FILTERS[i], function(selectedID) {
                var selections = [];
                for (var i=0; i<pickers.length; i++) {
                    var curPicker = pickers[i];
                    var sel = curPicker.options[curPicker.selectedIndex].value;
                    if (sel)
                        selections.push(sel);
                }
                console.log('Updating chart with filters: ' + selections);
                refreshChart('{!chartID}', '{!object.ID}', selections);
            });
            pickers.push(picker);
        }
    }
```

I am using the `JSINHTMLENCODE` to encode in the following way

```
var FILTERS = {!JSINHTMLENCODE(filtersJSON)};
```

After encoding the variable like above I am facing java script issues. The chart is not displaying.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you view the rendered source and paste us the JSON you're getting?

Comment: Can you expand on the JavaScript issues - it may be a simple syntax error.